# Как я могу вернуться к предыдущему фрагменту

Tags: java, android

Существует активность с панелью навигации, при нажатии на кнопки я открываю нужные мне фрагменты. Проблема в том, что если я возвращаюсь назад через кнопки самого телефона, ну или `onBackPressed()`, то ничего не происходит.

Могу ли я написать что-то в `onBackPressed()`, чтобы возвращаться к предыдущему фрагменту, как например у обычных активностей?

Дополнение:

В onCreate:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentMain();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).addToBackStack("back").commit();
```

После:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("back", 0);
    }
```

Comment: Вам надо добавлять фрагменты в стэк оных (addToBackstack("some unique tag")) в транзакции. Потом в onBackPressed надо проверять, что в сэке менеджера фрагментов есть оные и вызывать `popBackstack()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб приложение вылетает при попытке добавить в стэк, выше прикрепил код и проблему

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вроде нашел ошибку, все ровно спасибо

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все-таки не работает, выше еще раз прикрепил код, при попытке вызвать onBackPressed() ничего не происходит

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать popBackStack без аргументов

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все ровно не работает, причем тосты вижу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб заработало, благодарю! Вставлял не в том месте

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и еще, не подскажите как проверку сделать на наличие фрагментов  в стеке?

Comment: fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()